# How to make the "proximo"(next) button work and move the rocket(foguete)

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe, jbutton

I need to make my rocket move accordingly to the correct asnwer, if he(she) get it right, it will move(from the planet (left) to the (right) planet, else, it will do nothing, i have a counter for the right question, but i don't know what to do next.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.util.Enumeration;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;


    public class Jogo0 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
```

my variables

```
    JPanel QUIZ;
    JRadioButton opcao1;//choice1
    JRadioButton opcao2;//choice2
    JRadioButton opcao3;//choice3
    ButtonGroup escolha;//buttongroup
    JLabel questao; //question
    JButton proximo; //next button
    String [] [] alternativa; //alternatives
    String [] [] correta; //correct answer
    int acerto; //my counter


    int posifogx = 0; 
    int posifogy = 300;
```

the images to the code, rocket, background, planets

```
    ImageIcon imagfogut = new         v         ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Foguetao2.gif")); 
    ImageIcon imagespac = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Background.jpg"));
    ImageIcon imageplantale = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giphy.gif"));
    ImageIcon imageterra = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("terra.gif"));


    JLabel fog = new JLabel (imagfogut);
    JLabel background = new JLabel (imagespac);
    JLabel planetale = new JLabel (imageplantale);
    JLabel terra = new JLabel (imageterra);
```

my method jogo, that will run the whole game
        public Jogo0 (){

```
    Janela(); //window
    Imagens(); //img
    QuizMetodo(); //my quizmethod


                }

    public void Imagens (){ //imgs

    background.setBounds(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    fog.setBounds(posifogx, posifogy, 300, 200);
    planetale.setBounds(-150, 300, 259, 259);
    terra.setBounds(1000, 0, 379, 379);


                        }


    public void Janela()//window                {

    setTitle("Game");
    setLocation(0,0);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1920,1080);
    setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(fog);
    add(planetale);
    add(terra);
    add(background);

                                    }

    public void foguetex(int moverfoguetex) { //position of the rocket
    this.posifogx = moverfoguetex;
    moverfoguetex = moverfoguetex + 100;
                                        }

    public void foguetey(int moverfoguetey) {
    this.posifogy = moverfoguetey;
    moverfoguetey = moverfoguetey + 100;
                                        }

      public synchronized void QuizMetodo(){
      questoes();
      Container cont=getContentPane();
      cont.setLayout(null);          
      cont.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
      escolha=new ButtonGroup();     
      opcao1=new JRadioButton("Opção1",true);
      opcao2=new JRadioButton("Opção2",false);
      opcao3=new JRadioButton("Opção3",false);
      escolha.add(opcao1);
      escolha.add(opcao2);
      escolha.add(opcao3);
      questao= new JLabel("Salve seu planeta!");
      questao.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      questao.setFont(new Font("tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
      proximo=new JButton("Proximo");
      proximo.setForeground(Color.BLACK);                
      proximo.addActionListener(aa);
      opcao1.addActionListener(aa);
      opcao2.addActionListener(aa);
      opcao3.addActionListener(aa);
      QUIZ=new JPanel();
      QUIZ.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
      QUIZ.setLocation(250,530);
      QUIZ.setSize(800,150);
      QUIZ.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,2));
      QUIZ.add(questao);
      QUIZ.add(opcao1);
      QUIZ.add(opcao2);
      QUIZ.add(opcao3);
      QUIZ.add(proximo);
      cont.add(QUIZ);
      setVisible(true);
      acerto = 0;
      i = acerto;
      lerqr(acerto);
        }

      public String getSelection(){
    String selectedChoice=null;
    Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons=escolha.getElements(); 
    while(buttons.hasMoreElements()) 
    { 
    JRadioButton temp=(JRadioButton)buttons.nextElement(); 
    if(temp.isSelected()) 
                { 
                            selectedChoice=temp.getText();
                } 
     }  
    return(selectedChoice);

                            }

ActionListener aa = new ActionListener(){ //**I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE**

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



    }
    };

    public void questoes() { //questions
    alternativa = new String [10][4];

    alternativa[0][0] ="Qual é o composição química da água?";
    alternativa[0][1] = "(2) Hidrogênio e (1) Carbono";
    alternativa[0][2] = "(1) Hidroênio e (2) Oxigênio";
    alternativa[0][3] = "(2) Hidrogênio e (1) Oxigênio";

    alternativa[1][0] = "Pra que serve o Protocolo de Kyoto?";
    alternativa[1][1] = "Defesa dos animais";
    alternativa[1][2] = "Proteção contra emissão de gases";
    alternativa[1][3] = "Codigo da reciclagem";


    correta = new String [10] [2];
    correta[0][0] = "Qual é o composição química da água?";
    correta[0][1] = "(2) Hidrogênio e (1) Oxigênio";

    correta [1][0] = "Pra que serve o Protocolo de Kyoto?";
    correta [1][1] = "Proteção contra emissão de gases";


                        }


    public void lerqr(int id){
    questao.setText("  "+alternativa[id][0]);
    opcao1.setText(alternativa[id][1]);
    opcao2.setText(alternativa[id][2]);
    opcao3.setText(alternativa[id][3]);
    opcao1.setSelected(true);
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) { //my main method


    new Jogo0();
    }
```

Comment: Since you're using `null` layouts, have considered just setting the location of `fog`?

Comment: I considered it, but first i'd like to understand why my button is not working, or how can I make it work, and if get it right, to move the rocket

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if you need the methods foguetex(); and foguetey(); in the way you implemented them but the last line in both methods doesn't seem to affect the program in any way.

To make the rocket move and calculate the movement you could simply modify the foguetex(); method like this (or write a method with a different name if you also need foguetex(); for something else in the code):

```
public void foguetex(int moverfoguetex) { // position of the rocket
    this.posifogx = moverfoguetex + 100;
}
```

This will cause the value posifogx to get updated to the new x-value where the rocket should be (you can also modify foguetey(); if needed). After doing this you want to update the position of your JLabel displaying the rocket.
Therefore you reassign the bounds of the JLabel in the ActionListener similar to this (you possibly want to adapt it to the ActionListener you wrote yourself):

```
proximo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        foguetex(posifogx); //calculating new x-position
        fog.setBounds(posifogx, posifogy, 300, 200); //updating the label's position
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.